# How should one choose a journal when making their first attempt (ever) to be published?

Tags: paper-submission, university, publications

I am looking for the best place to publish a paper that I am preparing. It will be my first, and there aren't many clear and concise sources of information as to who is to be sought for the research I have been doing.

My question is, what are factors to consider in the choosing of a journal when publishing for the first time?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do not accept advice on this from people who have not read you paper.

Comment: Do you have an advisor or mentor? Academia is a bit like a craft in that you will have it 10 times harder to make progress if you don't have an advisor or mentor.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments,  @AnonymousPhysicist That particular thought for a change did not cross my mind. I should have seen that thank you.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Where would one find mentors on academia?

Comment: I think that @lighthousekeeper is speaking about an advisor at your university, assuming you are connected with one, perhaps as a student.

Comment: @Buffy I am indeed a student at a recognized university. I may have misunderstood the comment. my apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which journals do you read? Where do the references you cite come from? Where do your colleagues publish? This is very very subject-specific knowledge, but in any field there are a few key journals, varying in their specialised focus and in their reputation, and the experts know which they are because they use them.

Comment: Thank you Roger, I will keep that in mind, My specific industry is quite niche, as it is not mainstream work when it regards to my studies in the field. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 1):

It is really important to submit your research paper to a good quality journal. My suggestion is, submit your paper to DOAJ, WOS and Scopus indexed journal. Your paper may or may not get accepted in the first submission. But I am sure you will get a revision or feedback that will help you in develop your way of doing research.

Just make sure to submit your paper understanding the scope of the journal. If you submit to a journal that is out of scope. Without any feedback, the paper will get rejected.

There are numerous pay and publish, fast track journals, stay away from that.

Comment: Thank you Sulthan for making me aware of that, I will make a point to avoid the those. I want see my work published based on merit not currency. 

I have bookmarked those journals for further investigation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer does not differ whether you are publishing for the first time or the hundredth time. You should publish in the journal most suited to your research. That is, don’t choose a “worse” journal simply because it is your first time.

If you are having trouble thinking of which journal is most suitable because it is your first time, here are a few suggestions:

- Which journals do you read from?
- Which journals do you cite?
- Which journals do faculty in your field tend to publish in?
- Read any guidelines for publishing on the journal’s website. Think about factors like how long your paper is compared to others published in that journal, for example.
- Ask your advisor (presumably in your field) for advice.
- Have a few choices in mind in case your paper is not suitable/gets rejected at your top choice, **but only submit to one journal at a time.**

Comment: Thank you Kevin for your kind response. I will keep that in mind when making my choice.